# How to set distinct column entries as columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, dimensions, denormalization

I am trying denormalize a table in a way. I have a query that retuns an itemID a storeID and a quantity of that item sold at that store. Right now my table is thousands of rows long and only three columns wide. What I'd like to do is get only one row per store and have the itemID as columns where there is a quantity sold at that store for each itemID column. What is the best way to achieve this? my current query is below;

```
select 
distinct(itemID) item,
store,
sum(IitemQTY) as sumqty
from store_item_table
group by itemID, store
```

Comment: You need to look into using `pivot`.  Or if you know the number of potential items, you could use `conditional aggregation`.  Lots of examples on SO with each.

Comment: Personally i recommend using a Cross tab (conditional Aggregation) rather than the `PIVOT` operator. It is far more flexible than the built in operator; and many find it easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

no need distinct

```
select 
itemID as item,
store,
sum(IitemQTY) as sumqty
from store_item_table
group by itemID, store
```

Comment: Indeed... the answer was in the question: "one row per store and have the itemID as columns " ... IOW: For each item and store, what is the quantity? Simply group by those items, and sum the quantity, and BAM! Bob's your uncle.